# Mac Catalyst popover set/limit size problem

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

Is it possible to limit/fix (min/max) popover size on Mac Catalyst? See the attached video.

[Example video](https://i.imgur.com/4UXCiLc.mp4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but it's a bit of a hack. Big Sur is loading these presented view controllers as their own windows, so we can grab the window's `windowScene` and set its `sizeRestrictions`. The best (?) place to do this is in the *presented* view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method:

```swift
class MyPresentedViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
        if #available(macCatalyst 14, *) {
            view.window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
            view.window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 800)
        }
    }
}
```

If you don’t want the presented view to be resizable at all, just set the `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` to the same value.

I don't love using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` like this, but the `windowScene` is still nil in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, and while it is non-nil in viewDidAppear, setting `sizeRestrictions` there will cause a visible resize on screen.

The good news is that this problem may be fixed in Big Sur 11.1. According to the [beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_1-release-notes), macOS 11.1 will respect `preferredContentSize` *and* they won't be resizable by default:

> When you present a view controller with page sheet or form sheet presentation style, the size of the view controller’s root view is, by default, determined by the value returned from the presented view controller’s [preferredContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621476-preferredcontentsize) method and the view is not resizable. You can arrange for the presented view controller to be resizable by using Auto Layout to specify the maximum and minimum sizes of its root view. To enable this, set the [canResizeToFitContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/3368165-canresizetofitcontent) property of the application’s main window to YES. One way to do this is to override the willMove(toWindow:) or didMoveToWindow() methods of a view in the main view controller. (65254666)

Comment: Thx mate, I'll try it today on BigSur 11.1 and Xcode 12.3.

Comment: Indeed BigSur 11.1 & Xcode 12.3 fixed all the problems. Thx! :)

Comment: 'preferredContentSize' sets popup size and it works ok!

Comment: Not resizable by default, but you still get the resizing cursors. I've been looking in vain for a solution to keep the arrow pointer from switching.